# SQL Server SSD vs HDD performance

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

So I'm doing some performance comparison between SSD and HDD for SQL Server insert statements.

I'm inserting 2,000 columns worth of data across 4 different tables.

For each record I insert 1 row in each table.

I tested on one machine with a SSD as the main hard drive running the SQL Server process and the database file itself on a secondary HDD drive.

I tested on another machine with just a SSD drive that has both the SQL Server process and the actual DB file.

I would have expected the machine with the database field on the HDD to be slower than the machine with everything on the SSD.

Is this behavior I'm seeing expected? If so why?

Comment: It sounds like you are probably testing the cache memory on the HDD.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware issue

Comment: There's lots of data at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59828/ssd-vs-hdd-for-databases

Comment: @scottb, yeah, I was thinking something similar. I was thinking that maybe it was caching on the SSD first since that is the drive where SQL Server is installed and then it writes to the HDD later. Unfortunately I don't have a machine with SQL Server and just a HDD to test on.